# is there any way to get terminal width in v?

Tags: terminal, size, width, vlang

is There any way to get terminal width in V language?
I want to get terminal size (or just columns).
this is my code:

```
fn get_terminal_width() int {
    // help me
}
fn main() {
    width := get_terminal_width() - 5
    for _ in 0 .. width {
        print('=')
    }
    println('done')
}
```

Comment: Many shells have an environment variable called `COLUMNS`. So from `os` you'd call `getenv("COLUMNS")` to get a string, which you'd convert to a number. But Windows? I don't know.

Comment: @aMike there is no environment variable called COLUMNS... can you write an example?

Comment: Maybe it has to be exported from the shell?  `export COLUMNS`.  This is for Linux/BSD/macos/UNIXes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `term.get_terminal_size()`.

You can check out the documentation here (even if it is pretty empty for the moment): https://modules.vlang.io/term.html#get_terminal_size